# Get HTML code of PDF file opened with firefox's built-in PDF Reader in Python

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, firefox

You're probably aware of [Firefox's built-in PDF viewer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox-or-choose-another-viewer). The fact is that I'm trying to get the HTML code of the page displaying the file so that It would gave me more informations than the `PyPDF` library in python.
Obviously `requests` does not work because it's not a real link, so I thought about using `selenium` (maybe also in headless mode) with the `webdriver.page_source` attribute:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import os


service = Service(os.path.abspath('Files/geckodriver'))

options = Options()
# options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service = service, options = options)
driver.get(f'file://{os.path.abspath("Files/sample.pdf")}')
html = driver.page_source
print(html)
```

The fact is that this does not give me the complete source code, just the title and number of every page and the reference on the PDF file. For example, here's the page number 2:
`<a href="file:///path/to/pdf/Files/sample.pdf#page=2" title="Page ii"><div class="thumbnail" data-page-number="2"><div class="thumbnailSelectionRing" style="width: 100px; height: 132px;"></div></div></a>`.

Also for every page I got the same thing without knowing the content of every paragraph (notice that I've cut out all the code of the toolbar on the left side just for the explanation's sake) while in the Firefox Viewer I was able to see all the content.
So, I'm looking forward if some other method exists or if I have to fix something in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is a completely open source company. Please browse the source code to get access to that part of it. If you do not want access to the source code for the browser, then please be clearer in your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'd like to automate it with python. That's why I'm trying to get it with selenium.